# high order component throws an invalid react element error (reactjs)

Tags: reactjs, react-router, higher-order-components

So I've been reading about HOCs lately and decided to use them in my application to pass down authorisation logic to the child components.

I'm trying to render a `<Route />` component through the HOC but it logs the error:

> Uncaught Error: AuthRoute(...): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.

Here's the code for the HOC:

```
const AuthRoute = ({ component: Component }) => {
  class AuthComponent extends Component {
    // Authorisation logic here
    render() {
      return (
          <Route render={props => <Component {...props}/>} />
      )
    }
  }
  return AuthComponent;
};
```

And then I'm using this HOC as an alias of `<Route />` component like this:

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <AuthRoute path="/account" component={PrivateComponent} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

**EDIT:**

But this approach works fine:

```
const AuthRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
      checkAuth() ? (<Component {...props}/>) : (<Redirect to={{pathname: '/', state: { from: props.location }}}/>)
    )}/>
);

<BrowserRouter>
  <AuthRoute path="/account" component={PrivateComponent} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to review your architecture . Indeed, Your approach is **totally contradictory** regarding HOC pattern . You may need to do the following instead :

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Route path="/account" component={AuthRoute(PrivateComponent)} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

If you agree with this design of calling the HOC, The HOC implementation  will be :

```
const AuthRoute = (Composed) => {
  class AuthComponent extends React.Component {
    // Authorisation logic here
    componentWillMount() {
       if (!checkAuth()) {
         this.props.history.push({pathname: '/', state: { from: this.props.location }});
       }
    }

    render() {
      return (
          <Composed {...this.props} />
      )
    }
  }
  return AuthComponent;
};
```

Comment: This looks more familiar:)

Comment: @Abdennour Can you please explain a little about how my approach is totally contradictory in respect to the edit I made to the question?

Comment: Sure @m-ketan! I see your update that's why I updated my answer as well; Check out `componentWillMount`  Congrats!

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you are returning a class instance

```
const AuthRoute = ({ component: Component }) => {
  class AuthComponent extends Component {         
    // Authorisation logic here
    render() {
      return (
          <Route render={props => <Component {...props}/>} />
      )
    }
  }
  return AuthComponent;  // returning the class object here and not an instance 
};
```

So if your wish to use it you would need to write

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <Route path="/account" component={AuthRoute(PrivateComponent)} />
</BrowserRouter>
```

where `AuthRoute(PrivateComponent)` is a class object and Route creates an instance out of it internally

However in the second case, its not an HOC, but a functional component that returns a valid React Element,

```
const AuthRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
    <Route {...rest} render={props => (
      checkAuth() ? (<Component {...props}/>) : (<Redirect to={{pathname: '/', state: { from: props.location }}}/>)
    )}/>
);
```

and hence

using `<AuthRoute path="/account" component={PrivateComponent} />` , you called a component instance whereby props `path` and `component` are received by the functional component.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Glad it helped you understand

Answer (score 0):

I’m not very familiar with the syntax you wrote. But spotted one thing. Your parameter is component but inside you are using Component which in this context is undefined

Comment: Actually not undefined but React.Component

Answer (score 0):

It should be  :

```
const AuthRoute = (Component ) => { // <-- Component which refers to PrivateComponent
  class AuthComponent extends React.Component {  // <-- React.Component
     ....
```

and Not :

```
const AuthRoute = ({ component: Component }) => {

    class AuthComponent extends Component { 
      ...
```

Also check out [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47725162/747579) to have elegant HOC .